# Configure authentications of multiple micronaut declarative clients generated by openapi generator

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-openapi

hopefully somebody has some more clue than me.
I have an application with multiple modules built like in this documentation https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-openapi-generator-client-maven-java.html

I can see the configuration of the base path of the generated declarative client `openapi-micronaut-client-base-path=https://api.open-meteo.com/` but my server being called needs some basic authentication to be able to work with. I have different clients and they all need some different configurations.

I need a hint how to configure a specific client (in best case only by changing the configuration file)

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. I would have thought adding `clientId="myclient"` would have resulted in the `@Client("myclient")` annotation added to the client interface.